# Why would 1,2,3,4-tetramethyl-1,2-dihydro-1,2-diazete be aromatic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

[image: 1,2,3,4-tetramethyl-1,2-dihydro-1,2-diazete]

If the lone pair of the nitrogen on the bottom were to make the double bond with the nitrogen at the top, then the nitrogen on the top would have 10 electrons, meaning that the lone pair on the top nitrogen needs to shift to the left carbon.
Which will cause the π-bond electrons to shift and form a double bond with the bottom nitrogen.

In the end, each nitrogen will have a trigonal planar shape with two double bonds (one with carbon on the left and one with each other) and one single bond(?).

[image: 1,2,3,4-tetramethyl-1λ^4,2λ^4-diazete]

I do not understand how this structure would make sense.
This seems very unstable to be aromatic.

Comment: There's no such structure and the compound isn't aromatic.